# How can I partially render a page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to render a certain tag in my report if the relevant button is pressed. can anyone suggest me a solution

my navbar file is :

```
const navbar = () => (
  <Grid container justify="space-between" className="c-comp">
    <div>
      <ButtonContainedComp onClick={handleClick}>Sales</ButtonContainedComp>
      &nbsp;
      <ButtonContainedComp onClick={handleClick}>Deals</ButtonContainedComp>
      &nbsp;
    </Grid>
);

export default navbarComp;
```

```
import navbar from './navbar/navbar';
import SalesChartComp from './charts/sales/SalesChartComp';
import DealsChartComp from './charts/deals/DealsChartComp';


const ReportsPageComp = () => {
  return (
    <div className="reports_page_comp_root">
      <navbar />
      <div>
        <SalesChartComp />
        <DealsChartComp />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReportsPageComp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a separate route for each section using `react-router‍`, or another solution is: pass a setState function as a callback by props to `navbar` component, then in the navbar, set a value/state by your callback (parent setState) depending on which button is pressed...

after that, by using conditional rendering you can define which component must be shown.

e.g:

```
const NavBar = ({ onSelect }) => {
  const handleClick = (action) => onSelect(action);

  return (
    <Grid container justify="space-between" className="c-comp">
      <ButtonContainedComp onClick={() => handleClick("sale")}>
        Sales
      </ButtonContainedComp>
      &nbsp;
      <ButtonContainedComp onClick={() => handleClick("deal")}>
        Deals
      </ButtonContainedComp>
      &nbsp;
    </Grid>
  );
};

const ReportsPageComp = () => {
  const [action, setAction] = React.useState(null);

  const handleShowActions = () => {
    if (action)
      return action === "sale" ? <SalesChartComp /> : <DealsChartComp />;
    else return <h1>Please Click On on one of sales or deals button!</h1>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="reports_page_comp_root">
      <NavBar onSelect={(x) => setAction(x === "sale" ? "sale" : "deal")} />
      <div>{handleShowActions()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

***A point apart from the discussion:** you have to write your component names PascalCase.*

Answer (score 0):

You want to load content only when a button is clicked? did you already tried by using an HTML template like this? (very simplified version);

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    main content
    {{content_you_want_to_load}}
    more main content
  </body>
</html>
```

then, you use the structure {{content_you_want_to_load}}, first you transform your html to a string and then you use string manipulation to replace {{content_you_want_to_load}} by the actual contend you want to load and at the end you upload the resulting string. this is how i make it in php

Comment: My components are shared everywhere so I don't think this will work everywhere.